# HTML pattern validation RegExp not working in chrome

Tags: html, regex, google-chrome

I am using the below regex in my pattern attribute in Html for validating emails. (type="email" keeps the email with no domain extensions).

```
<input type="text" name="value" class="form-control" placeholder="Value" pattern="[-\w+.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?:,[-\w+.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}){0,4}"/>
```

But this is not working in the chrome, but is working fine in Internet Edge browser.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Also, this regex pattern is validating correctly in other sites.

Comment: Of course, `[\w-.]` must be `[\w\-.]` or `[\w.-]`